# Working with formulas in Django using Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I am getting a formula from a csv file. Suppose, the formula is score = x * 5 + y. Now I'm getting x and y value from the user. Any idea how should i proceed? I want to calculate the score. I'm using Django framework and want to calculate the score using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do so but **Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.**

```
// get value as string from your file
let formula = getFromFile() // 'x * 5 + y'
// get x and y from user
let x = getXFromUser() // 1
let y = getYFromUser() // 2

console.log(eval(formula)) // 7
```

Check out documentation for `eval` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).